# Python scraping selenium - table data not in code

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract the table data from this [page](https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=82594&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2).

Tried with bs4 and selenium, but the table data does not appear in the code, tried the wait mode in selenium also did not give.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=82594&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2'
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(url)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.page_source
```

Comment: change the link with this :  https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmDemonstracaoFinanceiraITR.aspx?Informacao=2&Demonstracao=4&Periodo=0&Grupo=DFs+Consolidadas&Quadro=Demonstra%c3%a7%c3%a3o+do+Resultado&NomeTipoDocumento=ITR&Empresa=ITAUUNIBANCO&DataReferencia=2019-03-31&Versao=1&CodTipoDocumento=3&NumeroSequencialDocumento=82594&NumeroSequencialRegistroCvm=1865&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is pandas to help you out. I did this. The output looks better though.
You may need to install `lxml` first.
so,first

`!pip3 install lxml`

then

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=82594&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)


dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
print(dfs[0].head())

#output
      0                                                  1  \
0    Conta                                          Descrição   
1     3.01               Receitas da Intermediação Financeira   
2  3.01.01                     Receita de Juros e Rendimentos   
3  3.01.02                              Receita de Dividendos   
4  3.01.03  Resultado de Operações de Câmbio e Variação Ca...   

                         2                        3  
0  01/01/2019 a 31/03/2019  01/01/2018 a 31/03/2018  
1               17.010.000               16.856.000  
2                6.142.000                5.973.000  
3                      NaN                      NaN  
4                  303.000                 -145.000
```